# Changing font size of button caption in interface builder (iPhone application)

Tags: iphone

Could you let me know how can I change font size of button caption in interface builder (iPhone application)/ or any API?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to show the Fonts window, by selecting the menu "Font -> Show Fonts" (or pressing Command-T).

Then, you select (highlight) the button in IB and change the font size on the fonts panel you just opened.